# setting style with jquery to paragraphs in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

its a very simple setup with some css and a line of javascript to make some changes:

```
#pass p {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="pass">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

```js
$("#pass > p").setStyle({backgroundColor:$('colorpicker3').style.backgroundColor});
```

does anyone know how to set style to all of the paragraphs with jquery ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `css()` method to set the style of an element in jQuery:

```
$("#pass p").css('background-color', $('colorpicker3').css('backgroundColor'));
```

Note however, that it's better practice to set your styles in your CSS and use `addClass` to set it on the required elements. Also, the `$('colorpicker3')` selector is not correct. Assuming it's a `class` you need to precede it with a `.`, or if it's an `id` it needs `#`.

Comment: I keep getting the css is not a function or cannot read property of null. ;/

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, you can add multiple css rules to a target by using

$(".targetClass > p").css({
  "background-color":"red",
  "color": "#fff"
});